# Suppressing output in python subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

For the following command:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split(
            """/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata 
              -apple_id %s -destination %s"""%(self.apple_id, self.destination))
```

It prints the entire output into the Terminal window. How would I suppress ALL output here? I tried doing `subprocess.call(shlex.split(<command> > /dev/null 2&1`)), but it didn't produce the required results. How would I do this here?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the `stdout=` and `stderr=` parameters to `subprocess.call()` to direct `stdout` or `stderr` to a file descriptor of your choice.  So maybe something like this:

```
import os

devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
subprocess.call(shlex.split(
    '/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata '
    '-apple_id %s -destination %s' % (self,apple_id, self.destination)),
  stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

Using `subprocess.PIPE`, if you're not reading from the pipe, could cause your program to block if it generates a lot of output.

**Update**

As @yanlend mentions in a comment, newer (3.x) versions of Python include `subprocess.DEVNULL` to solve this problem in a more convenient and portable fashion.  In that case, the code would look like:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split(
    '/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata '
    '-apple_id %s -destination %s' % (self,apple_id, self.destination)),
  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Comment: you can just use os.devnull

Comment: Hey look I learned something.

Comment: Using a predefined constant like this means that if the null device were something other than `/dev/null`, this would continue to work without needing to modify your code.  For example, I believe this returns something different but still useful under Windows.

Comment: what is the workaround for `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.call`? In that case it doesn't suppress the output

Comment: You would need to tell `subprocess.run` to collect the output.  See the documentation for the `stdout` and `stderr` parameters.

Comment: You can directly use `subprocess.DEVNULL` to suppress the output, no need to use os.devnull and open it.
`subprocess.call(shlex.split(
    '/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata '
    '-apple_id %s -destination %s' % (self,apple_id, self.destination)),
  stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)`

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me is appending `2>/dev/null` at the end of the command.

Comment: For future readers: this approach isn't guaranteed to work on all platforms/shells, even though it'll probably work on anything recent and POSIX-y.

Comment: (also, this only work with `shell=True`, which you want to avoid when possible)

Comment: @larsks why should I avoid `shell=true`? This solution is simple as hell and worked for my case.

Comment: @month See [the docs for details](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). In addition to the security issues noted there, you can also get unexpected behavior if your command string includes any shell metacharacters, and you can also run into annoying quoting issues.

Comment: @larsks thanks! In my case, there is no vulnerability through shell injection, since my command string is not constructed but hard coded (it actually just starts a necessary docker). But I'm definitely aware of the risk, now.

Comment: How? provide an example